# get sum method for negative number

Tags: java, sum

```
public void getSum(int a, int b) {
    int x=10;
    int y=-5;

    int ans = x;
    while (y != 0) {
        ans++;
        y--;
    }
    System.out.println("ans = " + ans);
}
```

This program gives correct answer but I do not understand how. Because `y` is `-ve` and I am doing `y--` which makes it go away from `0` and not towards it. So how is this program giving me correct answer?

Comment: Presumably this runs a really long time and both overflows `ans` and underflows `y`. `Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and then you keep going until it is `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `int` can hold a maximum value of `2^31-1` and a minimum value of `-2^31`. When the value exceeds these values, integer overflow occurs, which just means that you go over, it wraps around and the number becomes the opposite sign. (If you add one to the max value it will become `-2147483648`)

Let's put this another way. Envision a clock, except it goes from `0` to `2147483647` (At where `6` would be), and then immediately to `-2147483648`, and then back to `0`. (Note that `-2147483648` and `2147483647` are on either side of where `6` would be on a regular clock)

```
                         (0)
                          |




(-1073741824) -           *               - (1073741823)




                          |  
            (-2147483648)   (2147483647)
```

So say `y` is one hand and starts at `-5` and starts moving toward the `-2147483648`, and `ans` is 10 and is moving toward the `1073741823`. As the loop continues and `y` keeps moving counter clockwise, `y` will pass from `-2147483648` to `2147483647` and eventually go to zero, exiting the loop. Meanwhile `ans` will have also passed from `2147483647`   `-2147483648` and then stop when `ans == 5`.